# How to join dataframes in for loop efficiently | computation speed btw join, merge, concat

Tags: python, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

I m writing a code for dimension reduction of ~4000 time series files. By dimension reduction I mean I manually extract mean/std by time periods (4 in a day, by season, by weekday/weekend).

```
file = pd.read_csv('test/Res/1002', sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
file.drop([col for col in file.columns if "Unnamed" in col], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This is an excerpt - out of the 4 time periods in a day, showing the code for overnight period. The data have these columns: [daycode, val, day, hm, weekday] and based on the criteria for 'hm' values I extract data of a certain time period.

```
fcond = 1 <= file['hm']
scond = file['hm'] <= 14
overnperiod = file[file['hm'].isin([47, 48]) | fcond & scond]
overn_mean = overnperiod['val'].mean()
overn_std = overnperiod['val'].std()

overnperiod['daycode'] = pd.to_datetime(overnperiod['daycode'])
overnperiod['weekday'] = overnperiod['daycode'].dt.dayofweek

fcond = 0<= overnperiod['weekday']
scond = overnperiod['weekday'] <=4
wd_P1 = overnperiod[fcond & scond]
we_P1 = overnperiod[overnperiod['weekday'].isin([5,6])]
```

Again the following is part of the lengthy code for different time periods.

```
summer_P1 = overnperiod[overnperiod['day'].between(172, 264) | overnperiod['day'].between(537, 629)]
winter_P1 = overnperiod[overnperiod['day'].between(355, 443) | overnperiod['day'].between(720, 730) | overnperiod['day'].between(1, 79)]
```

So..7 of the following are the extracted features from a meter's time series data. (4000 x 7 total)

```
overn_PR = overn_mean/head_P 
breakf_PR = breakf_mean/head_P
day_PR = day_mean/head_P
evng_PR = evng_mean/head_P

std_year = overn_std/overn_mean + breakf_std/breakf_mean + day_std/day_mean + evng_std/evng_mean

season_score = abs(wd_P1['val'].mean() - we_P1['val'].mean())/overn_mean + abs(wd_P2['val'].mean() - we_P2['val'].mean())/breakf_mean + abs(wd_P3['val'].mean() - we_P3['val'].mean())/day_mean + abs(wd_P4['val'].mean() - we_P4['val'].mean())/evng_mean

week_score = abs(winter_P1['val'].mean() - summer_P1['val'].mean())/overn_mean + abs(winter_P2['val'].mean() - summer_P2['val'].mean())/breakf_mean + abs(winter_P3['val'].mean() - summer_P3['val'].mean())/day_mean + abs(winter_P4['val'].mean() - summer_P4['val'].mean())/evng_mean
```

For now my idea is to create dataframe per each meter and somehow add all under the header of meter ID. However since I can't use `append` inside the loop -> `concat` outside the loop technique, which compensates the low efficiency of speed by using `concat` inside the loop, I wasn't sure of the option left.

It seemed to me(by intuition..not certain) that `join` is faster, but to create an empty dataframe and joining in the loop.. `if` condition to

Alongside, I have gotten to wonder whether there is any speed difference in `merge`, `concat`, `join`.
Any thoughts?

Comment: For best performance, don't perform dataframe join / merge / concat in loops at all. Aggregate your dataframes in a list, then apply `pd.concat` outside the loop as a single step.

Comment: Wait..but the dimension will be (7by 4000), like a list. Do you mean to say use nested list structures?

Comment: not a major difference when I tested, but opted to vstack arrays and concat outside. couldn't figure a way to turn nested list into dataframe simply..maybe possible if using the index/for loop using zip outside the loop.